# Relation between the coefficients of $az^3+bz^2+cz+d=0$, when $\Re(z)<0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, cubics

> If all the three roots of $az^3+bz^2+cz+d=0$ have negative real part, and $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, then
>
> 1. $bc>ad$
> 2. $bc<ad$
> 3. $bc=ad$
> 4. None of these

I'm not quite sure how to proceed with this question. Also, is it possible to solve it logically, without any lengthy calculation?

Comment: If you want to solve it without performing any kind of calculations then I would suggest that you should choose three complex numbers which have negative real parts and form an equation with them keeping in mind that the coefficients must be real that is the roots should be chosen accordingly and then check if any of the given conditions hold or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the example of
$$(z+1)^3=z^3+3z^2+3z+1$$
shows, the only possible options are 1 and 4. Let us show that $bc>ad$.

Since $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are reals the roots of the equation have the form
$$r_1=x+iy, r_2=x-iy, r_3=t$$
where $x,y,t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x<0, t<0$. Assume for now that $a=1$ so that
$$d=-r_1r_2r_3=-t(x^2+y^2)$$
while
$$b=r_1+r_2+r_3=2x+t$$

and
$$c=-(r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_2r_3)=-x^2-y^2-2tx$$
which gives
$$bc=(2x+t)(-x^2-y^2-2tx)=-2x(x^2+y^2)-4tx^2-t(x^2+y^2)-2t^2x$$
Since $x<0$ and $t<0$ we have
$$-2x(x^2+y^2)-4tx^2-2t^2x>0$$
so that
$$bc>-t(x^2+y^2)=d$$

The general case reduces to this one by looking at the equivalent equation
$$z^3+\dfrac{b}{a}z^2+\dfrac{c}{a}z+\dfrac{d}{a}=0$$